# When date only is required to save, Converting it to UTC and then to local may behave differently in different time zones

Tags: datetime, localization, timezone

I have a date field at front end. And I am saving it from a time zone say 19/04/2018 and I am on +8. When I load it on local datetime.ToLocalTime() works perfectly in +8 offset and it will show 19/04/2018 but a person sitting in +7 would get in 18/04/2018 23:00 and hence it will show 18/04/2018. How to handle this case.

Comment: If programming language, platform or date-time library matters, which are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In general: you should not convert date only to UTC, so you should keep it as local date.

But it really depend on the use of data.

If you are using for some synchronization (all invoices until a fix point), a time with timezone is good, but in such case, also hours and minutes should be included.

If you care about the date written in an invoice, you may not transform date to UTC (so keep local date). If you aggregate invoices, you may wait until the day is passed on all timezone (and people filled all invoices into the system).

When people are looking into the data, what they expect? (case #1 or case #2). Then evaluate what kind of data you need. In the first case, you should add also (at minimum) the hours and minute (timezones never have seconds).

In general, if you have only a date, you are mostly on second case.

Comment: Well said.  Date-only values should not be converted to UTC.

Comment: Will if we do not convert a date only field, there is shopping date saved by a client sitting in Pakistan timezone (PST) and another client is sitting in New Zealand time zone. The client sitting in New Zealand timezone should consider it to his/her local date or Pakistan date? Date totally changes in other time zone in this case. Our date is different from their date. This may also occur for other countries like USA. How to handle it then?

Comment: If you display the date to user, it should be user date: for user there is just one timezone and localisation: its local. If you are using it just internally, use Packistan date. In any case, any choice you do, it should be used further without correcting for timezone.  If you are unsure (or if you really need both), put into database "datetime with timezone", so you can convert to any timezone, but you know also the original user timezone.

Comment: We have this solution like saving user's current timezone and when displaying that date in any region consider user's time zone (who saved the rec) but we already had saved records in so many tables and its almost impossible to identify every single rec in db and save offset so that while converting it to local we should consider it. and as app is enterprise level its very difficult to identify date fields and save offset with it. So we are looking for some valuable solution which can save our time. Like writing some extension method in business rule or any other trick which can work for us.